# ExtJS sprite to PDF, convert units

Tags: php, pdf, extjs, mpdf

I have a sprite with a document background, user can move to sprite.text over it and i save x and y pos of my texts. I assume the x/y positions are in pixels.
Then I want to create a **A3** PDF from this draw container with the texts using MDPF in PHP 7.
The coordinates for the PDF generation are in millimeters and i can't find the formula to convert my pixels to millimeters.

Some people suggested (pixels * 25.4) / DPI (96 is the default value for MPDF) on this website but it doesn't work I can't get the right position for every string length.